# Fetch Google sees 301 redirect

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301, ranking

*Background info: Some of my website innerpages had malware on it last week. The whole site has been reset, updated en cleared from malware a couple days ago. The website is SE optimized, but not spammed at all.*

**Q:** Some innerpages of the website have suddenly dropped from the Google results.

1. Searching site: http://www.domain.com/innerpage doesn't even give a result.
2. Searching cache: http://www.domain.com/innerpage has no results since today

**Webmaster page error:** The page seems to redirect to itself. This may result in an infinite redirect loop. Please check the Help Center article about redirects.

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 28 Oct 2013 20:15:18 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.21
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=170fc3f0740f2eb26ed661493992843a; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Pingback: http://www.domain.com/xmlrpc.php
Location: http://www.domain.com/innerpage/
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

The .htaccess file looks fine too. Do you guys have any idea what going on here?

The page is w3c valid and even online googlebot simulators show state 200 OK.

Comment: After several months it turned out that it was because of a virus. Google Webmasters showed me the info yesterday